# Pygame pygame.init() error

Tags: pygame

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trc\Documents\SPWT\Python Maths Quiz\trial-pygame\first.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I have not named my file pygame.py either. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: Use  **import pygame; print dir(pygame)** and tell what it is printing.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just recently encountered this problem with my program. What i had found to help me was to download the Source code from http://pygame.org/download.shtml . For me i am using arch Linux so it wasn't in my repositories or AUR. Next after that i went to the directory through my terminal typing these commands:

```
# python3 config.py
# 2to3 setup.py -w
```

Note you will need root access to use this command.

```
# python3 setup.py
```